# Rhythmbox Plugin To Browse Your Music By Folders

Tags: rhythmbox

Rhythmbox is good player but there is no choice to browse music file in folder browser.

Is there a workaround available?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This is a poorly formatted question.

Comment: This sounds like a software recommendation question, but as maggotbrain says, it's not clear function you are looking for.

Answer (score 12):

I too was looking for this feature. It can be done as follows:

I wanted to play songs based on folder, which is not possible using default.

Using Edit - Preferences, add the Location field.  Then sort by this field by clicking the header of the column.

This image shows how to play songs by folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All that can be done at this point is to press Ctrl+O, but this only allows a user to select a music folder. For now, Rhythmbox lacks that feature. However, Clementine is a music manager that allows the feature that you seek.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I always want to browse my files by folder. There used to be a plugin, but it seems to be discontinued. I found an other workaround, though: Install `minidlna`. Rhythmbox supports DLNA devices. And as any other DLNA client it gives you the option to browse the files, that are provided via a DLNA server by folder. 
Install DLNA:

```
 sudo apt instal minidlna
```

Configure `minidlna`:

```
sudo nano /etc/minidlna.conf
```

Start it:

```
sudo service minidlna start
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to create an automatic playlist using "path" as selection key for a specific folder.
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5qyW.png)